# New on Ubuntu Server

Tags: boot

I am new to Ubuntu. The issue that I am running into with ubuntu 18.04 server, is when I try to configure a static IP. I enter all the right information. At the moment of hitting "save" Ubuntu starts over.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you please edit your question to clearly explain what you mean by "Ubuntu starts over", and exactly which steps you are following to set the static IP address.

Answer (score 0):

Don't have enough cred to post a comment, but search for ubuntu 18.04 yaml, 18.04 and up uses netplan which so far i've found yucky but I'm also partial to liking changes!

This site link may explain more to you about how to go about it, or search for netplan and yaml. https://www.tecmint.com/configure-network-static-ip-address-in-ubuntu/